# Loading a local file during import

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a python script (dataloader.py) that loads some data from a file (data.csv) in the same directory as a module-level global. When I execute the module it loads the data file correctly, but when I import the module from a file (main.py) in another directory it cannot find the data file.

My file structure:

```
main.py
myModule/
    __init__.py
    dataloader.py
    data.csv
```

How can you load data from a local file during import, if the import can be called from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__file__` always returns the current file.

```
dataReader = csv.reader(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/data.csv")
```

Comment: I like your answer but it does not work. `dirname` returns the directory component of the path `__file__` but `__file__` is just the filename, does not have a path. You probably meant  `os.path.abspath(__file__) + ...`. 
So please edit  your answer.

Also you can use `os.path.sep` instead of the literal `/`, to abstract from OS. See also `pkgutil.get_data(package, resource)` for loading resources from a package.

Comment: For me `__file__` contains the path to the file and the file itself. `os.path.dirname` gives me the absolute path to the folder, which is what I needed. Using a literal `/` works on both Windows and POSIX.

Comment: You are right (sorry for that).  IF the module is imported, which is what was asked by the way. But in a script you run directly it has just the filename of the script (that led to my mistake). So maybe "always returns the current file" but not always with the full path. Didn't know the `/` detail. Nice.